# Upload an image on a hidden input using selenium

Tags: python, image, selenium

This question has been asked many times over the years but all the answers I've found have been outdated.

With modern websites, the input element tends to be hidden. I'm trying to upload a file to a social media platform as the profile picture. I've tried finding the hidden input element and entering the file directory of the png/jpg but no luck.

I don't want to use libraries like `pyautogui` because I want the program to run fully automatously in the background of the users computer.

The upload is covered by an `<svg>` and underneath there is a `<label>` & `<input>`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the file you trying to upload with this command:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys(the_path_to_the_file_on_your_pc)
```

?

Comment: yeah, doesnt work

Comment: What error do you see? Can you share your code and the link to the web page you are working on?

Comment: There's no error. It can find it and click it but it just doesn't upload. I'm working on Twitter.

Comment: Please share all your relevant code

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file_upload']"))).send_keys(file_path)`

Comment: This element will never be clickable, it is hidden! You should use `presence_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable`

Comment: Did this resolve your problem?

Comment: Was just about to write. No, it seems to find it and input it well. When I do it manually, you select the file then it shows if you want to crop the image. Instead it just sits there. There is no button to press upload.

Comment: Sending the file directly to `//input[@type='file']` works different than uploading it manually via the GUI. This will not open you the OS dialog to select the file on your disk and will be no step of pressing the "upload" button. It sends the file directly from your disk to the web page

Comment: So how can I upload it the

Comment: Just send the file as I mentioned. No need to click upload button.